# How to effectively build sitemap using PHP?

Tags: php, html, xml, sitemap

I have build a simple site map script, i am not able to get URL output in URL field.

My PHP Script.

```
    header("Content-Type: text/xml;charset=iso-8859-1");
    echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
          xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
          http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
    ';

    require_once('_ls-global/php/sr-connect.php');
    $db = mysql_select_db($database,$connection) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
    $sqlquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tablename ORDER by id")or die (mysql_error());

    while ($list = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlquery)){

      $pflink=$list['pflink'];
      $pagelink=$list['pagelink'];

      $site="http://mysite.com";

      $url='$site/$pflink/$pagelink';

      $changefreq="weekly";
      $priority="1.0";

      echo '<url>
          <loc>'.$url.'</loc>
          <changefreq>'.$changefreq.'</changefreq>
          <priority>'.$priority.'</priority>
            </url>';

    }

    echo '</urlset>';
```

The Output of this script is this.

```
    <url>
    <loc>$site/$pflink/$pagelink</loc>
    <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
    <priority>1.0</priority>
    </url>
```

If i change `$url='$site/$pflink/$pagelink';` to `$url="$site/$pflink/$pagelink";`

then i get only one value and error "XML Parsing Error: not well-formed".

Please see and suggest any modification to make it work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are having characters in the vars which are messing up the XML.

For example `&`, `ä`, `<`, `>`... You need to encode the content correctly.

Try wrapping the output:
At first change `$url` to `$url = $site .'/'. $pflink .'/'. $pagelink;` and then update the output of the XML to:

```
<?php
// ...
      echo '<url>
          <loc><![CDATA['.$url.']]></loc>
          <changefreq>'.$changefreq.'</changefreq>
          <priority>'.$priority.'</priority>
            </url>';
?>
```

Explanation to `CDATA` available at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA

Comment: Tried this getting error `XML Parsing Error: junk after document element`

Comment: Can you copy the output of the document to http://www.pastie.org or something like that (you might need remove the ``header()`` function at first)

Comment: I need the entire output (remove the ``header()`` function and the first ``echo()`` with the document declaration ``<?xml version="...`` and pos ta link again please. And: copy the source code (from browser) or encode the entire code with ``htmlspecialchars()`` - easier for you would be the first one (copy the source from browser).

Comment: your answer helped me most, and @FrontEndJohn comment made it right.

Answer (score 1):

Based on **thedom** and **FrontEndJohn** answers and comment I got it right this way.

Changing `$url='$site/$pflink/$pagelink';` to `$url = $site .'/'. $pflink .'/'. $pagelink;`

And modifying.

```
      echo '<url>
      <loc>'.$url.'</loc>
      <changefreq>'.$changefreq.'</changefreq>
      <priority>'.$priority.'</priority>
        </url>';
```

to

```
    echo '<url>';
echo '<loc><![CDATA['.$url.']]></loc>';
echo '<changefreq>'.$changefreq.'</changefreq>';
echo '<priority>'.$priority.'</priority>';
echo '</url>';
```

Hope this helps others too.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you cannot currently get the value of the variable due to the use of ' but when trying to use " so that the variables echo the XML gets upset.

**Try:**

```
$url = $site . '/' . $pflink . '/' . $pagelink;
```

This will give the value of the variables without using ". If I have miss-understood you please let me know.

**Edit:** Thinking about it, it looks more the the value of one or more of the variables may be what is upsetting the XML, assuming the variables are not giving their values while using '. It could be worth checking the contents of the variables for issues if you have not done so already.

Comment: Using your solution or using " i get only one values and still the error `XML Parsing Error: not well-formed`

Comment: Maybe the added white space is giving you some problems then also, as @thedom has mentioned below, encoding could also be playing a part so in conjunction with tidying you variables, encoding your output, also remove as much whitespace as possible such as the white space within the echo statement at the end. Either wrap each line in a new echo or use a single line with inserted     . "\r\n" .   to break the lines.